# jQuery: Set auto height on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the `class` inside of the `<li>` tag to be auto height/adjustable to its `<li>`, however it wasn't possible with CSS(`height:auto;height:100%` and other options) so I tried jQuery but I'm a newbie so I tried what I've learned so far.
 The following code does just what I need but I wasn't able to figure out how to set the auto height for the class on page load instead of `.click` function. Please note that I have many `<li>` tags with different sizes so `(this)` needs to be included.

```
$j("#accordion ul li").click(function () { 
  var current = $j(this).height() - 2;
  $j(this).find(".status-green").attr("style","height:" + current + "px");
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$j(function () {
    $('#accordion').find('.status-green').each(function (index, value) {
        var $value = $j(value),
            h      = $value.parents('li').height() - 2;
        $value.height(h);
    });
});
```

This will find and iterate through each `.status-green` element within the `#accordion` element when the DOM is ready (`$j(function(){});` is short-hand for `$j(document).ready(function(){});`).

**--Update--**

This more closely resembles your code:

```
$j(function ($) {
    $("#accordion").find('li').each(function (index, value) { 
        var $value  = $(value),
            current = $value.height() - 2;
        $value.find(".status-green").height(current);
    });
});
```

If you pass `$` as a argument in the first line then you can use `$()` rather than `$j()`. Also the `.height()` function assumes pixels if only a number is passed to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jasper. I tried it but it didn't work. I have a JavaScript conflict so I'm using $j , I'm not sure what is the problem, it looks like this now: `$j(function () {
    $j('#accordion ul li').find('.status-green').each(function (index, value) {
        var $jvalue = $j(value),
            h      = $jvalue.parents('#accordion ul li').height() - 2;
        $jvalue.height(h);
    });
});`

Comment: I updated my answer to more closely resemble the code in your question. The basic idea is to iterate through each of the `<li>` tags, get its height, and then set the height of any elements that have the `status-green` class inside of that `<li>` tag.

Comment: It finds the `.status-green` but it adds only this to it  `style="height:-2px"`

Comment: Maybe you can bind to the `window.load` event instead of the `document.ready` event: `$j(window).bind('load', function () {/*code here*/});`. If you have images in the `<li>`'s then they will need to load before a proper height can be calculated.

Comment: Not really it didn't work. The problem is it doesn't calculate the `#accordion ul li` height to set the height of `.status-green` inside of it.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized what was my main problem. I was using Display:None for the #accordion on my page, I removed it and set that with jQuery instead of stylesheet so the jQuery doesn't take it as disabled selector and it worked perfectly! Thanks again